# How to fix this shared_ptr reference cycles?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I designed an `App` that holds a stack of `layers` and an active `obj`.
When a `Layer` is attached to the `App`, the `Layer` tells `App` what an active `object` is. But my design causes a sigtrap when deallocating.

It cause sigtrap because the destruction of `shared_ptr<Obj> m_obj` in App happens first which reduce the `use_count` to 1. Then the `onDetech` function gets call, setting the active `shared_ptr<Obj> m_obj` to `nullptr` and reduce `use_count` to 0! But the `layer` still holds an `shared_ptr<Obj>`.

The code below is a minimal example to reproduce. I notice my code has a reference cycle but I have no idea how to fix this except using a raw pointer for `obj` in the `App` class.

I used `shared_ptr` for `obj` in `App` because it makes sense to me that `App` has the shared ownership of `obj`. Should I not use `shared_ptr` in this case?

```
class App;

class Obj {
   public:
    ~Obj() { std::cout << "obj destruct" << std::endl; }
};

class Layer {
   public:
    Layer() { m_obj = std::make_shared<Obj>(); }

    ~Layer() { std::cout << m_obj.use_count() << std::endl; }

    void onAttach(App *app);

    void onDetach();

    std::shared_ptr<Obj> m_obj;

   private:
    App *m_app;
};

class LayerStack {
   public:
    void pushLayer(App *app, std::shared_ptr<Layer> layer) {
        m_layers.push_back(layer);
        layer->onAttach(app);
    }

    ~LayerStack() {
        for (auto &layer : m_layers) {
            layer->onDetach();
        }
    }

   private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Layer>> m_layers;
};

class App {
   public:
    App() {
        m_defaultLayer = std::make_shared<Layer>();
        m_stack.pushLayer(this, m_defaultLayer);
    }

    ~App() {}
    LayerStack m_stack;
    std::shared_ptr<Layer> m_defaultLayer;
    std::shared_ptr<Obj> m_activeObj;
};

void Layer::onAttach(App *app) {
    m_app = app;
    app->m_activeObj = m_obj;
    std::cout << m_obj.use_count() << std::endl;
}

void Layer::onDetach() {
    m_app->m_activeObj = nullptr;
    std::cout << m_obj.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

```
int main() {
 A a;
}
```

output:

```
2
obj destruct
-923414512
-923414512
```

Comment: Thanks for th suggestion. I have updated my code example. But the issue I described still exists. The `use_count` gets decrease to negative.

Comment: It's not decreased to negative, you're just reading garbage. Address Sanitizer can find where you used after free: https://godbolt.org/z/s1YxbsWdc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing `m_activeObj` after its lifetime has ended, and thus the behavior of your program is undefined.

The sequence of events is as follows:

1. `App` object goes out of scope
2. `~App` runs
3. `m_activeObj` is destroyed; after this its lifetime has ended and it can no longer be accessed
4. `m_defaultLayer` is destroyed
5. `m_stack` is destroyed

   1. `m_layers[0].onDetach()` is called
   2. `onDetach` sets `m_app->m_activeObj` to `nullptr`, but its lifetime has already ended, so behavior is undefined.
6. Irrelevant other stuff; you're already screwed.

The solution is to reorder things so that you don't access `m_activeObj` after its lifetime has ended.  Either move `m_stack`'s declaration after `m_activeObj` so it gets destroyed first or clear it manually in `~App`.

Comment: Oh.. ok, I see it now.  One more question, why I am not getting a sigfault when reference a object that's destroyed?

Comment: Because undefined behavior is undefined.